# Why does Ruby class_eval remove constants from scope?

Tags: ruby

I made a class with a constant & a method:

```
class A
  FOO = 'hello'
  def bar
    puts FOO
  end
end

A.new.bar
=> 'hello'
```

And everything works as expected. However when I do this:

```
A.class_eval do
  def bar
    puts FOO
  end
end

A.new.bar
NameError: uninitialized constant FOO
```

Weirdness... To get around this I'm doing:

```
A.class_eval do
  def bar
    puts self.class::FOO
  end
end
```

Any good explanation on why this is so?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Constants are looked up

1. *outwards* in the lexically enclosing module declarations
2. *upwards* in the inheritance chain of the current module declaration

So, let's just do what Ruby does:

1. look outwards in the lexically enclosing module declarations: easy – there *are no* module declarations
2. look upwards from the current module declaration: again, there is no current module declaration … or is there? Well, if there is no module declaration, it is implicitly assumed to be `class Object` – but `Object` doesn't have a constant named `FOO` and neither do its ancestors `Kernel` and `BasicObject`.

Ergo: Ruby is right. There is no constant named `FOO` within the constant lookup path. It didn't remove `FOO` from the scope, it was never in scope to begin with.

[Ruby's reflection API actually gives you access to anything you need: #1 is exactly the same as `Module.nesting` and #2 is (almost) the same as `Module.nesting.first.ancestors`.]

You might think: wait, isn't `module_eval` a module declaration? No, it isn't! It's just a method like any other method taking a block that's just like any other block. It doesn't alter the constant lookup rules in any way.

Note that that's not quite true: after all, e.g. `instance_eval` *does* change method lookup rules, for example, so it would not be inconceivable that `module_eval` changes constant lookup rules. And even more confusingly, when called with a `String` instead of a *block*, it actually *does* change `Module.nesting` and thus the constant lookup rules!

Comment: So, which is it? Do `instance_eval`/`class_eval` alter constant lookup? From what I can see they don't. They just don't change `Module.nesting` to the value it'd have if you reopened a class/module.